# NFA: Regular Language that starts with ab but does not end with ab?

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

$L = \{x \in \{a,b\}^* \mid \text{$x$ starts with $ab$ but does not end with $ab$}\}$

I'm having trouble making a table for this NFA. I tried a few sketches out of the diagram and I can post them onto an image site if necessary. However if you choose to help, you can always put them in a table.

I get the main part, but for some reason I cannot construct this particular NFA.

Comment: I think I have managed to produce one that accepts all words starting ab. I am having trouble with implementing the ending with ab. I have a ton of these questions in exercises and wanted to example to go by.

Comment: @RachelKonti522 There are tons of examples already on this site: [tag:finite-automata].

Comment: Have you tried constructing a DFA and converting that?

Answer (score 2):

If you have managed to produce an automaton that accepts all words starting $ab$ and an automaton accepting all words that don't end with $ab$, you're most of the way there. You can then either use the product construction to take their intersection or use the same ideas you used to produce each individual automaton to produce a single automaton that performs both tasks.

For strings that don't end $ab$, mouse-over the hint below if you need it.

> Use the state of the automaton to "remember" the last two characters you saw. If they were $a$ and $b$ in that order, the state should be rejecting; otherwise, it should be accepting. That way, when you get to the end of the input, you're in an accepting state iff the last two things you saw were not $a$ and $b$, in that order.

Answer (score 1):

If you can´t draw a NFA from the definition of a language $L$ but you are convinced that $L$ is regular then you can try to write a regular grammar $G$ that denotes $L$.

For this example $G= \{N,\Sigma,S,P\}$ with:

$N= \{S,X,F\}$

$\Sigma= \{a,b\}$

$S=S$

$P= \{$

$\quad S\to abX | abb$

$\quad X\to aX | bX | F$

$\quad F\to a | bb$

$\}$

Now you can build a NFA from this grammar. The non-terminals are the states of the NFA. The initial state is the start symbol of the grammar. The transitions are obtained from the production rules of the grammar. We add auxiliar states as they are needed. The production rules of the type: $\alpha -> \beta$ with $\alpha \in N$ and $\beta \in \Sigma^*$ will lead you to a final state. Finally the NFA is:

[image: NFA]